# Return all rows from a table and information from another for specific row

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make a simple video rate system for a website using two tables, videos and ratings. Basically, there's a video record on the "videos" table, and then 1 or n ratings for that video id inside the "ratings" table. I can select a single video record and add a column based on the average of all the ratings for that video doing:

```
SELECT v.*, avg(r.rate) FROM videos v
LEFT JOIN ratings r
ON v.id = r.video_id
WHERE v.id = 100;
```

This returns:

```
id     |   name      |  file     |   rate
------------------------------------------
100    |   Testvideo | test.avi  |  4.4286
```

There are 7 rows for that id inside "ratings" ranging from integers 3 to 5, so the average is working as expected, if the specific video doesn't have a rating it'd throw null for the rate column but everything else shows up. So, I have the method for single ID covered up, but I can't figure out what the query would be if I want to return the whole video list in the same format

```
id   |   name      |  file        |   rate
------------------------------------------
1    |   test1     | test1.avi    |  5 
2    |   super2    | conan.avi    |  null
3    |   mega3     | wedding.avi  |  2.1149
```

I tried a lot of things, but they all returned either a single row (which I assume is because of the avg function) or duplicated rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY v.id`.

Comment: @Kenney You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I figured someone would mark it as duplicate - I've seen this before :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this, but indeed it works just as fine. Thanks! On a second note, would it be more performance to do the left join or the Gordon's method?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096910/sql-counting-and-numbering-duplicates-optimising-correlated-subquery) suggests that joins are significantly faster than correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT v.*,
       (SELECT avg(r.rate)
        FROM ratings r
        WHERE v.id = r.video_id
       ) as avgrating
FROM videos v;
```

Comment: Ahh, I see! I tried doing subqueries but inside all kinds of joins without realizing I could just put the subquery at the top. Thank you!

Comment: @arielhr Your original method was fine, you just forgot `GROUP BY v.id`

Comment: @Barmar . . . That might be true for MySQL, but not for SQLite.

Comment: I don't use SQLite, but I'd be very surprised if it can't use `GROUP BY` with a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, I'm so used to that MySQL extension that I forget it's not standard. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135997/why-no-select-foo-group-by-foo-id-in-postgres) suggests that SQLite also allows it (or did 6 years ago), and an answer indicates that it was added to PostGreSQL 9.1.

Comment: @Barmar . . . I forgot that SQLite is like MySQL, because this is a "feature" I never use.  Postgres's use of id's in the `group by` is based on an ANSI standard definition of something called "functionally dependent", which basically means that primary and unique keys can be used this way.

Comment: That restriction makes sense, and all the times I've omitted columns from GROUP BY I think it's been the case. It will catch the erroneous queries that try to get the max/min row of a group the wrong way.